# Как можно сделать адаптивную таблицу, в которой все ячейки будут одинаковые по ширине?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Приветствую! Подскажите, как можно сделать адаптивную таблицу, в которой все ячейки будут одинаковые по ширине?

```js
< link href = "https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"
rel = "stylesheet" >
  < script src = "http:/ / code.jquery.com / jquery.js " > < /script>
  < script src = "https:/ / netdna.bootstrapcdn.com / bootstrap / 3.0.0 / js / bootstrap.min.js " > < /script>
```

```html
<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>текст</th>
      <th>текст</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>текст</td>
      <td>65151, 652511, 652712, 6923, 6923-71, 74131, 7429, 7429-52, 75165, 79091, 79092, 74296, 7930, 69234, 74296, 543, 692374, 65272, 6527</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>текст</td>
      <td>80, 82, 1523</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте правило CSS

```
table-layout: fixed;
```

на таблице.
Только адаптивность таблиц всегда спорна. Если имеете в виду "адаптивность" по-бутстраповски с `.table-responsive`, то мой вариант должен работать. Если  трансформацию в список, как предлагают на bootsnip, то тут - не знаю.